# Sticking back the output of the R 'table' command to a dataframe

Tags: r

I am looking for a way of sticking back the output of the 'table' program to a data frame.
I get the example from https://www.statology.org/table-function-in-r/

```
df <- data.frame(player = c('AJ', 'Bob', 'Chad', 'Dan', 'Eric', 'Frank'),
                 position = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'),
                 points = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0))

df

  player position points
1     AJ        A      1
2    Bob        B      2
3   Chad        B      2
4    Dan        B      1
5   Eric        B      0
6  Frank        A      0

#calculate frequency table for position variable
table(df$position)

A B 
2 4
```

Now I would need to add another column to df, using the 'expanded' output of the above table command, like this:

```
  player position points table  
1     AJ        A      1   2
2    Bob        B      2   4
3   Chad        B      2   4
4    Dan        B      1   4
5   Eric        B      0   4
6  Frank        A      0   2
```

Is there any command that would do the job?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
 within(df, table <- ave(player, position, FUN = length))
#>   player position points table
#> 1     AJ        A      1     2
#> 2    Bob        B      2     4
#> 3   Chad        B      2     4
#> 4    Dan        B      1     4
#> 5   Eric        B      0     4
#> 6  Frank        A      0     2
```

Comment: You could just use `transform` in base R as well: `transform(df, table = ave(player, position, FUN = length))`

Comment: @Allan Cameron Thanks, but why I need to consider also the player column if I need to score only the position one?

Comment: @Arturo you don't really - any vector the same length as the number of data frame rows will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr, you can count the number of elements by position with a grouped mutate. For example

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(table=n(), .by=position)
#   player position points table
# 1     AJ        A      1     2
# 2    Bob        B      2     4
# 3   Chad        B      2     4
# 4    Dan        B      1     4
# 5   Eric        B      0     4
# 6  Frank        A      0     2
```

Comment: This also does the trick, though needs an additional library. On the other hand the dplyr package gives much more flexibility and might be wort learning it.